# Syntax errors while trying to change a foreach loop

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl and I am trying to learn enough of it to refactor a few lines of legacy code.

Here is a snippet of the code that I have:

```
my ( $data2 ) = @_;
foreach $app (@{$data2->{record}})
{
...
    if ( $app->{submission_date__required_} )
    {
            $datetime = convert_date( $app->{submission_date__required_}, "both" );
            print $datetime;
    }
}
```

What I tried to do is this:

```
my $data = pop $data2;
my $app = $data->{record};

if ( $app->{submission_date__required_} )
{
    $datetime = convert_date( $app->{submission_date__required_}, "both" );
    print $datetime;
}
```

Any explanation of what I am doing wrong and how to achieve what I need (retrieving the last item from the loop and assigning it to $app instead of iterating through the whole loop) would be appreciated.

I have weird errors in the logs and the page won't load. Here is what the error log says:

```
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value in lc at submitapp.pl line 48.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $notix in print at submitapp.pl line 177.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $store in string eq at submitapp.pl line 249.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $store in string eq at submitapp.pl line 258.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $store in string eq at submitapp.pl line 267.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $operating_mode in string eq at submitapp.pl line 287.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $operating_mode in string eq at submitapp.pl line 300.
[Tue May 10 14:55:20 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Use of uninitialized value $operating_mode in string eq at submitapp.pl line 328.
[Tue May 10 15:09:10 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] syntax error at getqbdata.pl line 415, near "), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/qb/submitapp.pl?action=Submit
[Tue May 10 15:09:10 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] \t\tprint", referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/qb/submitapp.pl?action=Submit
[Tue May 10 15:09:10 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Execution of getqbdata.pl aborted due to compilation errors., referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/qb/submitapp.pl?action=Submit
[Tue May 10 15:09:10 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Premature end of script headers: getqbdata.pl
```

Nevermind, after apache restart #9 it finally worked.

Comment: [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) needs to be passed an array, not an Hash reference. I think you want `my $data = pop @{$data2->{record}};`

Comment: The syntax of the posted code is correct. The error you are getting isn't a syntax error. Could you provide the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data2` is a reference to a hash.  The `pop()` function takes an array as an argument.  Because `$data2` references a hash, there is no concept of a "last" element to remove.  So you're going to need to rethink what it is you're trying to do.

In your case, the loop was iterating over the array referenced by `$data2->{record}`.  You can access the last element of **that** with `pop`, however:

`my $app = pop @{$data2->{record}};`

Comment: The only problem I have when I try to do my $app = pop @{$data->{record}}; is that I get an Internal Server error. I kept everything else the same, though.

Comment: @marat75, That's not useful. What error is Perl giving? Probably in your web server log.

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the errors from the apache log.

Comment: @marat75 you are aware that pop removes an entry from an array, right?  if you just want to get the last entry without modifying the array, do `my $app = $data2->{record}[-1];`

Comment: Yes, but it is getting discarded after this step, so it does not truly matter.